# How to easily list columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm have a table with many columns in BigQuery.
I wanna list its columns in select query, but listing the all columns is hard.

I wanna do like this

```
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  ...
  SOME_METHOD(col30),
  ...
  col50
FROM
 foo.bar;
```

Is there any ways to write such query easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(col30), SOME_METHOD(col30)
FROM foo.bar
```

or

```
SELECT * REPLACE(SOME_METHOD(col30) as col30)
FROM foo.bar
```

for example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3, 4 col4, 5 col5
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(col3), 2 * col3 AS col3
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row col1    col2    col4    col5    col3     
1   1       2       4       5       6
```

or

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 col1, 2 col2, 3 col3, 4 col4, 5 col5
)
SELECT * REPLACE(2 * col3 AS col3)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row col1    col2    col3    col4    col5     
1   1       2       6       4       5
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untested in Big Query, but one trick which is available in other databases, such as SQL Server, is to do a `SELECT *`, but then also list other items you want to select.  So you may try one of the following:

```
SELECT *, SOME_METHOD(col30) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Or

```
SELECT SOME_METHOD(col30), * AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Note that depending on what the other things are you explicitly list, you could end up with the same column (and name) appearing more than once in the result set.